# PHP help for parsing XML

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse XML and print a tag but I am getting error saying.

Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getElementsByTagName()

```
<?
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->load('http://www.espncricinfo.com/rss/content/story/feeds/0.xml');
        $item = $doc -> getElementsByTagName('item');
        $title = $item->getElementsByTagName('title');
        $titles = $title->item(0)->nodeValue;
        echo "<h2>$titles</h2>"
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This line returns a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php):

```
$item = $doc -> getElementsByTagName('item');
```

This line calls method `getElementsByTagName()` on `$item`:

```
$title = $item->getElementsByTagName('title');
```

However, `$item`, a `DOMNodeList`, does not have the method `getElementsByTagName`, hence the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getElementsByTagName()
```

To work with rss feeds I recommend you just use SimpleXML:

```
function h($s) {
    return htmlspecialchars($s, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
}

$u = 'http://www.espncricinfo.com/rss/content/story/feeds/0.xml';
$rss = simplexml_load_file($u);
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    echo "<h2>",h($item->title),"</h2>\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Avila. But I tried as you suggested SimpleXML but its not throwing any error but its printing nothing in the page.

Comment: I did added echo "Test: <h2>",h($item->title),"</h2>\n"; And it did printed text multiple times but just Test:

Comment: @mysteriousboy the `h()` function is missing a `return`. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`$item` is a DOMNodeList, not a DOM element, use this to access the first element in the list:

```
        $title = $item->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('title');
```

This uses the [`item()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php) method to get the first element in the list.